# How can i add colon (:) in my qr barcode content?

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code, zxing

I'm using `zxing` library for my app. I want to add a colon `:` to my QR code string. Here is my code:

```
val encoder = BarcodeEncoder()
val content = StringBuilder()
content.append("Name" + ":" + name_et.text.toString() + " ")
content.append("Email" + ":" + emailAddress_et.text.toString() + " ")

val bitmap = encoder.encodeBitmap(content.toString(), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500)
iv_barcode.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

if I add a colon to my content I get no output from my QR code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this article will be useful for you, here is a clear description of how to generate a barcode, I think it will help you because everything is clearly written here step by step

> https://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/howto-creating-barcode-kotlin-android

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into ZXING? I've been using it successfully to create barcodes. You can see a full working example in the bitcoin application src

```
// this is a small sample use of the QRCodeEncoder class from zxing
try {
// generate a 150x150 QR code
   Bitmap bm = encodeAsBitmap(barcode_content, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 150, 150);

   if(bm != null) {
    image_view.setImageBitmap(bm);
   }
} catch (WriterException e) { 
//eek 
}
```